# Ajax запрос редиректит на свой url

Tags: php, ajax, yii2

Доброго времени суток, собственно ajax запрос просто редиректит на урл, который я ему указываю(index/add), а должен возвращать в консоль строку.

Запрос:

```
function testPen(){
$('#regBTNfirst').click(function () {
    var c = function (e) {
        console.log(e)
    };
    //c($('input[name="RegistrationForm[email]"]').val());
    $.ajax({
        url:"add",
        type:"POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data:1,
        success:function(data){
            c(data)}

    })
})
}
testPen();
```

Контроллер:

```
 public function actionAdd()
{
  return json_encode('ne_rabotaet');
}
```

Comment: **#regBTNfirst** у вас случаем не тег **a** ?

Comment: Нет, button, type="button"

Comment: Ну в любом случае **$.ajax** сам по себе не умеет редиректить, скорее всего либо на button где то еще навешено событие, либо она каким либо образом отправляет форму. Ну то есть приведите пример окружающего вашу кнопку html, ну и просмотрите не навешиваете ли вы где нибудь **$('button')**, **$('buttonClass')** либо еще покакому селектору в которые попадает данная кнопка